# Show a function is decreasing

Tags: calculus

I'm having some trouble finding a way to prove that the following function is decreasing

$f(x) = \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{3^m-2}{3^m-1} + \dfrac{1}{(3^m-1)(3^m)^x}\right)^s}{\dfrac{6^m-5}{6^m-2} + \dfrac{3}{6^m-2}\left(\dfrac{2}{6^m}\right)^x}$

where $m\in\mathbb{N},m \geq 2, x\geq 1$ and $s=\log_36$.

Taking the derivative is rather complicated (I did it in Wolfram Mathematica) and I haven't found a good way to go from there to show that the resulting expression is negative.

Definition of decreasing seems a little less painful but I run into the issue where the numerator of $f(x)$ and denominator of $f(x)$ are both decreasing and I'm not sure if there's a way to analyze that further to show the whole function is decreasing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you also include the original problem?

Comment: The problem comes from research I'm doing in fractal geometry, so there isn't exactly any formal problem statement.

Comment: If you write $f(x) = (g(x))^s/h(x)$ and use quotient rule for derivatives, you just need to show $(g(x))^2h^{\prime}(x) - s (g(x))^{s-1}g^{\prime}(x)h(x)$ is negative. If it helps...

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't think  $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

I think I made a mistake in my previous answer. Since my answer can't be deleted, I update it to clarify the argument. My point is that this function can't be decreasing.

Let $f(x) = \dfrac{(a+ \frac{1}{kb^{x}})^s}{c+ \lambda d^x}$, where $a,c,d,k,\lambda <1; b>1$ are some positive constants (compare these letters with terms depending on $m$ in the original function. For a fixed $m$ & $s$, these can be considered constants).

Note that, {$1/kb^{x}$} decreases since $b>1$. Hence, {$a+ \frac{1}{kb^{x}}$} is decreasing as well.  Moreover  $a+ \frac{1}{kb^{x}}< 1$ & $s>1$; therefore, 
{$(a+\frac{1}{kb^{x+1}})^s$} is decreasing as well.

Similarly,{$c+ \lambda d^x$} decreases since $d<1$.

Now , let $p(x)$ & $q(x)$ be the numerator & the denominator of $f(x)$ , respectively. So, $p(x) > p(y)$ & $q(x) > q(y)$ for all $x<y$. Thus, $1/q(y) > 1/q(x)$.

$f(y)=\dfrac{p(y)}{q(y)} > \dfrac{p(y)}{q(x)}$

That's all we can conclude.  It's not possible to prove the desired result.